# Is “reach out and touch” an idiom?

Tags: idioms

Is “reach out and touch” an idiomatic expression?

> The manual for the console versions describe him as “half unfeeling machine, half raging horned devil. This walking nightmare has a rocket launcher for an arm and will definitely reach out and touch you.”

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberdemon) quoting [NOW Gamer](http://www.nowgamer.com/features/top50gamesmoments/1157268/48_facing_the_cyberdemon_in_doom.html). It can also be found in the Depeche Mode song “Tainted Love”.

Comment: A small correction: It's not Tainted Love. It's [Personal Jesus](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1xrNaTO1bI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase *reach out and touch* is is an idiom because it deliberately conflates two or more different meanings of the word *touch* and cannot be understood based on the literal meaing of the words used.

The word *touch* in the phrase is a verb form, and is preceeded by the phrase *reach out*.  In this context, it  suggests the following meaning ([transitive verb, meaning 1](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/touch))

> To cause or permit a part of the body, especially the hand or fingers, to come in contact with so as to feel: *reached out and touched the smooth stone*.

However, the context in which the phrase *reach out and touch* is used rarely, if ever suggests an actual touching. Rather, in the tagline that made it famous, as described in other answers, the contact was at long distance.

Instead it could more readily convey *being in touch*.  This phrase uses *touch* as a noun form. The phrase *in touch* means ([noun, meaning 14](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/touch))

> The state of being in contact or communication: *kept in touch with several classmates; out of touch with current trends*

Finally, the word touch can convey an emotional, rather than physical contact ([transitive verb, meaning 10](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/touch)).

> To affect the emotions of; move to tender response: *an appeal that touched us deeply*.

Given the layers of meaning, and the non-literal usage, it is an idiom,

Comment: I don't think this is an *idiom*, merely a metaphorical use of an ordinary utterance. *Reach out* might be regarded as an idiom, depending on whether you include phrasal verbs; but if you treat that phrase as sememic, then the entire sentence could be translated word for word into French or German with no change of meaning.

Answer (score 5):

> reach out and touch someone

was used as a very common idiom in the [1980s by Bell systems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO17B-ACRn0). Bell systems coined the phrase in their commercial, which caught a hold of society. [Bill and Ted](http://www.billandted.org/soundsexcellent.htm) traveled through time in a glass phone booth, which the use of the phrase fit perfectly for the scenario. =D

EDIT: To further establish that the above is still considered an 'idiom' and not solely an 'ad tagline', a simple 'define idiom' search in google provides:

> A group of words established by usage as having a meaning not
>   deducible from those of the individual words (e.g., raining cats)

In which "reach out and touch [...]" does just that.

Comment: It's an ad tagline, not an idiom.

Comment: Or an idiom used in an ad tagline?

Comment: If it was coined for the ad (which seems likely; anybody care to do a corpus search?), then by definition it was not an idiom at that time. Whether it has since become an idiom or not is a philosophical question for another day.

Comment: It's not an idiom like "raining stair-rods", it's a metaphor (or simply figurative).

Comment: @Marthaª Where do I induct phrases as idioms? Do you have a link? Whether or not it was used as an advertising pitch has no leverage over whether or not the substance of the expression is idiomatic in nature. The definition of an 'idiom' matches the usage of the phrase.

Comment: @Martha: I think it's possible for ad taglines to evolve into idioms. A couple other candidates for idiom status might be "Have it your way," "99.44% pure," "Where's the beef?" "Betcha can’t eat just one," as well as the more-recent "I’m lovin’ it," and "That was easy."

Comment: I've never heard "99.44% pure" outside of an Ivory Soap ad.  For that matter are they still using it in their advertising at all?

Comment: @Marthaª: It's worked its way into the language as an idiom. I heard a Marine sniper on TV recently describe the [Barrett M82](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_M82) as a great choice "when you need to reach out and touch someone." This man wasn't even born when AT&T was running those spots.

Comment: That's good evidence that it's reached idiomatic status in some quarters at least: gangsta idiom. Still a cliché, though, like many idioms.

Comment: @Dan: for what it's worth, I've heard people use the 99.44% number in jest when they wanted to explain how something was "almost" perfect, like, "I agree with Robusto 99.44% of the time."

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that it qualifies as an "idiom", but "reach out and touch someone" is a well-known poetic phrase meaning to make emotional contact with another human being. Using it to describe a weapon is intended to be ironic.

Comment: I'll upvote this if you put quotes around poetic ;)

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna disagree with both answers (and agree with Marthaª) and say that it's just *warm, fuzzy* **advertising lingo** from the days when one had to pay an arm and a leg to call long distance using a landline telephone instead of Skype. It's calculated to press your money-belt buttons to turn the money-belt into a jackpot ejaculating Las Vegas slot machine transferring your wealth into the bank account of Ma Bell or whatever other phone service provider you had to deal with. Rather than an *idiom*, I'd call it an **advertising *cliché***.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment to Martha, I think it's possible for an ad slogan to evolve into an idiom (particularly when one gets a boost during a [presidential debate](http://www.popscreen.com/v/5ZTrs/1984-Mondale-Wheres-the-beef)). Whether or not "reach out and touch someone" has made the transition would be up for debate – I'd call it borderline, but won't take any more of a stance than that.

Comment: I agree. The one that strikes me as an established idiom is **Just do it!**

Comment: Bill, I almost included that one, but refrained, because I wondered if that one went in reverse (that is, it became a tagline after it was already an idiom).

Comment: I don't know which came first. Maybe the OED has a record of it. "According to a case study conducted by the Center for Applied Research, the slogan was born in a Nike meeting with the Wieden & Kennedy advertising agency in 1988. At the meeting, Dan Weiden reportedly complimented the Nike team for its can-do attitude, saying "You Nike guys, you just do it." This seems to be a case of what Gary Gilmore said before he was executed, "Let's do it!", turning into "Just do it!" at Nike.

Comment: The link is a million characters long!

Comment: I have to upvote both your answer and @Mechaflash's. You'll find "reach out and touch" all over Google Books ever since the 1870s. 1888:"The Importance of Chapter Letters to a Fraternity Journal can not as I verily believe be overestimated. For is it not a fact that through them we expect to reach out and touch the memories and arouse the interest of our alumni?"   1903: "It is an elemental instinct of man to reach out and touch his neighbor, to listen for his voice, and to be satisfied only as he is included in some group." I'd say the Bell folks exploited an existing warm and fuzzy cliché.